# Why don't add a link with the last and the next question?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add the ability to go to the next/previous question when viewing a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/add-the-ability-to-go-to-the-next-previous-question-when-viewing-a-question)

When we are on the question page, for read the next question, we can go back, and click on the list for read the next question.

Why don't add a "short linked" on the last question and on the previous question when we are on the question page?

Sample:

```
[previous question]   TITLE QUESTION PAGE   [next question]
```

Comment: Interesting how this exact same idea was popular in the past (+19/-1) and now it's not. (+3/-4 in less than 15 minutes) :/

Comment: If I don't feel like flipping back and forth, I'll just CTRL-click a bunch of questions so they open in new tabs.

Comment: oh..Ok. Sorry,  I search if question not duplicate... I bad search... I'm Ok with control click, but when you read question in your smartphone, in the mobile vesrion, it's very not practical...

Answer (score 5):

It's much more efficient to select which questions to read based on the title than on position in an arbitrary list. A lot of lists are sorted by time asked or time of last activity. If I only care about Perl questions and know nothing about C#, and a Perl question was asked between two C# questions, what benefit do I get from a "previous" and "next" link? I won't be able to answer them, and they won't help me.

Even when the list is sorted by relevance to search terms, the subject of each question could be pretty different from the next one in the list. There is already a "Related" section to the right that lists questions that are related by subject matter, not position in an arbitrary list of question.

I just don't see the benefit of such a feature.

Comment: I am agree with you, BUT, If I know Perl and c#, And I like read lot of question for know problem, the point of view of lot of people, have a previous and next linked are perfect... 

And now, when we are a problem in one language, we can learn from other language for resolved it...

You don't think ? 

And, when you read question in a smartphone, is more easy and fatser click in next button than go back in the previous page and click the next question...

For you, (in sample) you can always return in the main page for select your question....

Comment: So you're saying you like to read a lot of questions? Why not use the "Related" section to go directly to another question? Or go back to the list and see which question titles actually catch your interest, rather than reading questions that happen to sit next to ones that do?

Comment: just for read lot of ACTUALY question... and when I say it in my re-edit : 

For you, (in sample) you can always return in the main page for select your question....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say...could you try re-wording you last comment please?

Comment: I'm sorry, my english is very bad.
I say just for you , with previous and next button, you are no change, you can juste go back and selecting your next question...

It's just better for me , for all people using a stackoverflow's mobile webiste and maybe other...

Answer (score -1):

Personally I like this idea. I *know* that a Stack is not a forum, but the collection of questions is *analogous* to the list of questions on a forum, and forums have such links, and many forum users like them. I've learned, based on my experience Sheriff-ing at JavaRanch, that some people absolutely love those "next thread"/"prev thead" links, while other people never touch them. I'm in this second group, as it turns out, but I try to appreciate other points of view.