# Navigate to the next question in the context?

Tags: discussion, navigation

Is there a userscript/browser plugin to add/create a hotkey/link to navigate to the next question in the current context?

Every time I search stackoverflow site or scan through a tag / list of newest questions I have to go to search results or index to open next question.

RSS reader allows quick browsing browsing through questions with hotkeys but lacks functionality of full-blown site. Moreover its inconvenient to subscribe to a tag you are not going to visit tomorrow.

There are [hotkey userscripts](https://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts), but they lack this functionality.
[There is a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/add-the-ability-to-go-to-the-next-previous-question-when-viewing-a-question) for this functionality to be implemented on the site and I'm looking for any kind of solution.

Comment: Just open the questions up in a new tab rather than navigating using a single tab.  Then you keep your page with the search results or question list, and even keep your place on it.

Comment: @Servy, that's what I do. Still this requires at least two more actions - close the tab, select next question with hotkey, open it with hotkey.

Comment: If other sites can do it (see griddlers.net, for example), then it shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: I understand you want more rep and that you wrote something you're happy with, but creating a dupe just to publish it isn't very right.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard, I've actually wasted my night on it after asking a question. And question you mention is about site functionality, not external tools.

Comment: Still, its a fair place to mention it. Edit; I see you have, good good

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a prototype of userscript. Find it [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/180096). It only works for stackoverflow.com and meta.stackoverflow.com for now.